# Page for not yet existed tag contains link to 404 page

Tags: bug, tags, feed, 404-not-found

Recently I added not existed tag to my favourites list (via "Favorite Tags edit" link on the right hand side of the homepage). Tag info page contains a link to RSS feed:

> [image: t tag]

Such link refers to 404 page. My thoughts that a such link should produce empty RSS feed, or even should no be visible at all.

Comment: My thoughts are that if the tag doesn't exist, it shouldn't have a feed. A 404 is correct.

Comment: Arguably, the tag info page should also be a 404.

Comment: @Oded I like your second comment more than first one :)

Comment: The link should definitely be a 404... the link shouldn't really exist though.